# Interpolate function in python scipy

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, interpolation

Let's say I have the data, where
x values = dates from 1st January and the next 30 days, and
y values = for every date, which % of users from my website were active on it

Then I want to build plt.plot on X and Y and make it smooth.

When I interpolate the data using any scipy functions I found, some y values are always negative or > 1, which doesn't make sence. How to avoid it?

Comment: Without actual code is hard to know why this happens (it is better if you can provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), but have in mind that interpolation artifacts may always happen (occasionally reaching values higher or lower than those of the original data).

Comment: `from scipy.interpolate import pchip`  and `yi = pchip(x, y)(xi)`